# Insert data from CSV file to Cassandra table with auto generated UUIDs and timestamp

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, datastax

I want to insert data from a csv file to Cassandra table with auto generated UUIDs and timestamps.

**Cassandra Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
myid text,
mytype text,
mymodels set<text>,
myname,
created bigint,
PRIMARY KEY (myid, mytype)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (mytype ASC);
```

**CSV File**:

```
mytype|mymodels|myname
"type1"|[model1,model2,model3]|"name1"
"type2"|[model1,model4,model5]|"name2"
```

I want to generate UUIDs and timestamps on the flow.

Tried `COPY` command from [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertCopyCSV.html) with csv file as:

```
myid|mytype|mymodels|myname|created
uuid()|"type1"|[model1,model2,model3]|"name1"|blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(now()))
uuid()|"type2"|[model1,model4,model5]|"name2"|blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(now()))
```

Doesn't work. Is there any alternative for this?
If None, Is it better to manually hard code UUIDs and timestamps (the ugly way of doing) in the CSV file or write multiple `INSERT` statements for each record in a file and execute it or use [BATCH](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html) feature of Cassandra?

P.S. Record count is around 150 to 200

Comment: Where is the updated field in the table schema ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam My bad, removed it from the CSV file.

Comment: just FYI - `BATCH` isn't necessary an optimization in Cassandra it may work well only if all records in batch belong to the same partition key